# PHP Update query is notworking

Tags: php, mysql

**Guys** I'm getting some problem to updatemy data so helpme out to resolve this problem as soon as possiible. 
I am getting response of something went wrong I dont no why?
i am getting syntax error of my update query mainly the column name time  and i'm confused.so please provide right syntax

```
$query= "UPDATE nesbaty_offer SET  'offer_punch' ='$offer_punch',
                                 'offer_description' ='$offer_description',
                                 'terms' ='$terms',
                                 'sales_discount' ='$sales_discount',
                                 'referal' ='$referal',
                                 'duration' ='$duration',
                                 'billing_type' ='$billing_type',
                                 'status' ='$status',
                                 'service_location' ='$service_location',
                                  'time' ='$date'
                                  where 
                                  offer_id = $offer_id";
```

Comment: use backticks no single quotes arround column namens

Comment: I suggest you to check the linked question which shows the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a syntax error in your query.try this one

```
$query= "UPDATE nesbaty_offer SET  offer_punch ='$offer_punch',
                                 offer_description ='$offer_description',
                                 terms ='$terms',
                                 sales_discount ='$sales_discount',
                                 referal ='$referal',
                                 duration ='$duration',
                                 billing_type ='$billing_type',
                                 status ='$status',
                                 service_location ='$service_location',
                                  `time` ='$date'
                                  where 
                                  offer_id = '$offer_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks Brother !!!@Rahul Shrivastava

Comment: please vote up to my 
ye harami sala 
question marked as duplicate by u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

remove qoutes for column

```
$query= "UPDATE nesbaty_offer SET  offer_punch ='$offer_punch',
                                 offer_description ='$offer_description',
                                 terms ='$terms',
                                 sales_discount ='$sales_discount',
                                 referal ='$referal',
                                 duration ='$duration',
                                 billing_type ='$billing_type',
                                 status ='$status',
                                 service_location ='$service_location',
                                time ='$date'
                                  where 
                                  offer_id = $offer_id";
```